# Sound does not finish playing entirely before the second one starts

Tags: android

I am developing an application for research purposes. The app requires two sounds of 500 milliseconds each to be played one after the other, with a gap of 500 milliseconds between them. The problem is that the first sound does not finish playing entirely. It gets cut towards the end.

```
public void playSounds(int num, int i) {

    if (num == 1) {

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            mp.reset();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[i]);
        //i--;
        mp.start();
        //onPrepared(mp);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            mp.reset();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[0]);
        mp.start();
        //onPrepared(mp);
        Log.d("Mytag", "RevCount is " + revCount);


    } else if (num == 2) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            mp.reset();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[0]);
        mp.start();
        //onPrepared(mp);

        Log.d("Mytag", "RevCount is " + revCount);
        try {

            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            mp.reset();
            //Thread.sleep((long) 500.00);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[i]);
        //i--;
        mp.start();
        //onPrepared(mp);


    }
}
```

I've already initialized the mediaPlayer object. I just cannot seem to find what's wrong here.